# Laravel simple awards system

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, echo

So I watched a video on laracasts, where the tutor was talking about events and listeners. He created an event for payments, and then a listener for a coupon award. However since it was just a lesson about events and listeners and not about the awards, he just var_dumped some data to the page and was done with it.

*This is the episode:*
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/49

I am now left wondering how one should go about this. If for example I have a bootstrap modal that should pop up and say 'You got a coupon', am I supposed do just echo something like this:

```
echo '<script> alert('You got a coupon!'); </script>';
```

*(I tried the example above with the alert thing, and it sort of worked, but I am still not sure if that is the proper way to do things)*

I think you get my point. I am wondering if this is how one is supposed to do it or if one is supposed to start working with websockets.

So maybe I create a second event called 'Coupon Aquired', and then that event is broadcasted on a private channel, dispatched inside the listener for the first event, and then a user subscribes to the private channel and listens for that particular event.

*(I started implementing this, but I am totally confused, this is my first time using websockets and I am wondering if they are even supposed to be used for this kind of thing)*

I am really having difficulty asking proper questions here, since I rarely get to talk to other devs. I hope this made at least some sense xD

Comment: Hi @Max, We are also using this system actually but it's with websocket spec socket.io & redis. Example: Teacher creates a modul for a classroom, classroom has student's, Every student gets a notification. We are publishing this to redis via `Redis::publish` to a specific channel, `socket.io` listens this events via `ioredis`, when this events fires, we are sending an emit from `socket.io` to user. We are using a system like this for our website :)

Answer (score 0):

> So maybe I create a second event called 'Coupon Aquired', and then
>   that event is broadcasted on a private channel, dispatched inside the
>   listener for the first event, and then a user subscribes to the
>   private channel and listens for that particular event.

Yeah, something like this. 
I think you should have event `PaymentEvent` with specific user info (like `id` etc.) I'm not seen video, but If u need to show `Coupon Award` popup for every Payment - just create two event listeners : `UserPaymentListener` & `CouponAwardGrantedListener` or something like this. 
If purpose is only send to front - u even not need `eventListener`. Just create websocket connection between front and back (laracasts have great tutor how to achieve that - https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io/episodes/1?autoplay=true) & broadcast event there.
There are many ways to achieve what u need, but u r definitely on a right path. 
Good luck!